# Cannot import PYMC

Tags: python, enthought, canopy, pymc

When I try to import PYMC installed with `pip`, `enpgk` or the canopy GUI `package manager`, I tried all of them and without success.

```
Enthought Canopy Python 2.7.9 | 64-bit | (default, Jun 30 2015, 22:40:22) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-55)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pymc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/renanpc/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from .CommonDeterministics import *
  File "/home/renanpc/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc/CommonDeterministics.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .utils import safe_len, stukel_logit, stukel_invlogit, logit, invlogit, value, find_element
  File "/home/renanpc/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc/utils.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import flib
ImportError: libgfortran.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried to install GFORTRAN with :

```
~$ sudo apt-get install gfortran-4.6
```

but I still get the same error.

(there are other questions very similar indeed, but usually the answer has to do with Anaconda and I'm using Canopy)

Any idea of what is going on ? I can import other packages.

Comment: Can you install gfortran by means of the Canopy package manager?